# how to pass named parameters to function in python

Tags: python-3.4

I have a function A with two named parameters and a function B that will optimize the result of A, changing its arguments. The algorithm is the same regardless I optimize the first or the second parameter. Can I pass to B the name and the value of needed parameter? 
  The question raised while looking at scikit-learn functions of machine learning.

I want something like this:

```
def A(p1 = 0, p2 = 0):
   print(p1 + p2)
def B(par_name, par_val):
    ...
```

B will call A with given parameter.

```
B("p1", 1) => A(p1 = 1, p2 = 0)
B("p2", 1) => A(p1 = 0, p2 = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call A with the keyword argument that you need. In a similar case i put the arguments from the calling function in a dict and pass his to the called function

```
def A(p1 = 0, p2 = 0):
  print(str(p1) + str(p2))
def B(par_name, par_val):
   para_dict = dict()
   para_dict[para_name] = para_val
   A(**para_dict)
```

Please see [Key Word Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) in the python docs for more details.

another way is, that your dict already has all keys p1, p2 with its default values and you are just update the key you want and pass it to A

```
para_dict = {"p1":0,"p2":0}
```

and it might be better to loop through the arguments in A

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use named arguments when calling another functions:

```
 def A(p1, p2):
   print("p1=%s, p2=%s" % (p1, p2))

 def B():
   A(p2="two", p1="one")

 >>> B()
 p1=one, p2=two
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want a bit another effect, see edited question.

Comment: IFrom you example it's not clear how does `p1` become `1` and `1`(2nd arg) become `0`

Answer (score 0):

The number and names of the parameters are fixed? If so, the best way is passing a dict as Joe Platano has mentioned.
Otherwise you can also do

```
>>> def A(p={}):
       # to print?
...    print(p.get('p1',0),' + ',p.get('p2',0))
       # or to compute?
...    print(p.get('p1',0) + p.get('p2',0))
...
>>> def B(key, value):
...     A(p={key:value})
...
>>> B('p1',1)
1  +  0
1
>>> B('p2',1)
0  +  1
1
```